# vim: C indent braces at the same level as case

Tags: c, vim

So far, I have the following `cinoptions`:

```
cino=
cino+=:0
cino+=g0
cino+=p0
cino+=(0
cino+={0
cino+=l1
cino+=t0
cino+=u2
```

I would expect that the `{0` option would indent as:

```
case 1:
{
    foo = 1;
    break;
}
```

but instead it indents as:

```
case 1:
    {
        foo = 1;
        return;
    }
```

Is there a way to make it indent as the former?

(Not a duplicate. This question is asking about braces alignment ... the person is asking about stuff inside the braces. The other answer does not help me solve the problem. I can already achieve what the other question is answering but that is not what I am asking about. If you don't have the patience to read through to realize it's a different question, please don't mark it as duplicate.)

Comment: I have a blank `cino` and it gets the behavior you want...

Comment: `set cino=`? That indents the braces two levels for me ...

Comment: Knowing `vim`, there's probably some interaction with other options. :(

Comment: Actually, I just started with a blank `.vimrc` with just the `cino` options and I get the same behaviour.

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question is asking about braces alignment ... the person is asking about stuff inside the braces.

Comment: 1) you don't **need** braces inside the case part. 2) you can always do manual indenting (eg with tabs and :se ts=4), which also enhances your flow.

Comment: ^ True. But I want to use braces for consistency in style with existing code ... I already know I can do manual indentation ... what do you mean be "enhances your flow"?

Comment: Actually, fount the answer: `cino+={-1s` instead of `cino+={0` works.

Comment: @mtahmed Now that the question is reopened, you could answer the question yourself with the solution you found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cino+={-1s`

instead of

`cino+={0`

works. Basically, the default is `0s` which places it indented in. `-1s` places the braces as desired.

Comment: When I use cino={-1s the lines after the brace are getting set to double the shiftwidth. I have not set any other cino values.
Right now, I am making do with set cino==0 when I am indenting case labels with braces, else I remove this option and indent for case without braces.